# How to execute methods right after dismissViewControllerAnimated completion block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I've got a view controller called `CommentEditorViewController` presented modally and here is the code to dismiss it:

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonTouched:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"doneButtonTouched");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [[ImageStore sharedStore] setComment: self.textView.text forImageWithIndex:self.imageIndex];
    }];
}
```

It works completely fine, but the problem is that the parent view controller's (which is called `PhotosViewController`) `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` methods are being executed before this block. And I can't figure out, how to execute code right after this block completion. Should I do all this stuff in the block? If it is so, how should I do this?

Comment: if you want that code to execute  with dismissViewCOntroller, put that code before the line dismissViewControllerAnimated. If you use completion block, your code will only get executed when the child VC is dismissed completely. And ofcourse the there is a chance of getting parent viewWillAppear/DidAppear method gets called because the completion block is asynchronous and it doesnt guarantee that it will run serially!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to move that code before the *dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:* line , because the code written in completion block will execute when the viewcontroller is really eliminated , that just might be after *viewDidAppear* of parent viewcontroller.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was silly enough not to figure it out.